# is nested @ supported?

Tags: verilog, synthesis, yosys

I am trying to create an implicit FSM using the following syntasix:

```
always @(posedge clock) begin
   @(posedge clock)begin
       statement
   end
   @(posedge clock)begin
       statement
   end
```

It works fine in simulation but when I try to synthesize, an error displays:
"syntax unexpected @"

is this sintax not supported by yosys?

THX

Comment: It is supposed in simulation. It is not supposed by any synthesizer I know of. Nested `@`s would require the synthesizer to add registers which synthesizers don't normally do (sometimes they do remove registers to remove obvious redundant logic and optimization).

Comment: The IEEE Standard for Verilog Register Transfer Level Synthesis (IEEE Std 1364.1-2002) is very clear that this is not synthesizable Verilog. See sec 5.2 of the standard for details.

Comment: Thanks Clifford, (too much time coding in HLS make that things)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A high-level synthesis tool can support this and build a state machine from multiple clock edges in a single `always` block.  But I don't think yosys can handle it.

Comment: HLS tools don't process Verilog.

Comment: There were a number of Verilog synthesis tools that supported this. I worked on one of them when I was at Cadence.

Comment: @CliffordVienna yes but in most of them FSM are implicit (like in my post)